# What desktop enviroment is most efficent?

Tags: desktop-environments

I don't really care if the desktop environment is quick. What I want is a desktop environment that lets me open apps and get things done the fastest. I don't care about flashiness or anything.

READ: I am not looking for the desktop environment that is the lightest. I am looking for the one that lets me open an app and use it most effectively, to minimize,for example, the time it takes me to open libreoffice and write up an essay for school. I want to be super efficient.

Comment: @bain Read edit please

Comment: @Xubu-Tur Read edit please

Comment: If you are looking for something to speed up your application start you should use [preload](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2013/05/using-preload-ubuntu-13-04). To speed up libreoffice look at this http://itsfoss.com/speed-libre-office-simple-trick/

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of lightweight GUIs out there I would look into:
[XFCE](http://www.xfce.org/) and 
[LXDE](http://lxde.org/)

Comment: Read edit please

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad, every desktop environment has its cherry :-) one likes that the other one that, it depends on one's person criteria, if your computer has at least 1GB ram, 1.5Mhz processor, they all will function normally.

What kinds of desktop environments are available that can fit your taste look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

Comment: Well I don't care about looks. I don't care about speed. I'm just looking for a desktop environment that lets me do what I want to do most effectively. Nothing else really matters to me.

Comment: Well I consider the look of desktop environment it's what make you feel cozy and works out of the box, I like default `Unity` for example, it works effectively for me. For some people `Gnome` is better, again it depends on one's taste.